# Why the Dialog Box is opened multiple time even after animation is completed?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

onTap event I added an animation and called a dialog box from animation completed but the problem is that when I goto tap the button for the second time and start animation, the dialog box opens two times, when animation has completed & when I go for the 3rd time , dialog box opens 3 times and so on.

**CODE:**

variables:

```
double _angle = 0;
  double _current = 0;
  AnimationController _ctrl;
  Animation _ani;
```

initialized from initState() method :

```
 var _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 5000);
    _ctrl = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration);
    _ani = CurvedAnimation(parent: _ctrl, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
```

AnimatedBuilder:

```
 AnimatedBuilder(
    animation: _ani,
    builder: (context, child) {
      final _value = _ani.value;
      this.valueee=_value ;
      print("_value:$_value");
      final _angle = _value * this._angle;
      return center(
        child:GestureDetector(
           onTap : startAnimation,
           //
           //...

         ),
       ),
     },
 ),
```

I called it from onTap: event in Widget tree:

```
 startAnimation(){
    if (!_ctrl.isAnimating) {
      var _random = Random().nextDouble();
      _angle = 20 + Random().nextInt(5) + _random;
      _ctrl.forward(from: 0.0).then((_) {
        _current = (_current + _random);
        _current = _current - _current ~/ 1;
        _ctrl.reset();
        //_ctrl.stop();
      });
    }
  _ctrl.addStatusListener((status) {
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
         openDialogBox();
      }     
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

everyTime you call `startAnimation()` method ,you will call the `_ctrl.addStatusListener` method,then will add a new StatusListener to animationController.

just move `_ctrl.addStatusListener` below `_ani = CurvedAnimation(parent: _ctrl, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);`

like this:

```
    var _duration = Duration(milliseconds: 5000);
    _ctrl = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _duration);
    _ani = CurvedAnimation(parent: _ctrl, curve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn);
    _ctrl.addStatusListener((status) {
      if(status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
         openDialogBox();
      }     
   });
```

and

```
 startAnimation(){
    if (!_ctrl.isAnimating) {
      var _random = Random().nextDouble();
      _angle = 20 + Random().nextInt(5) + _random;
      _ctrl.forward(from: 0.0).then((_) {
        _current = (_current + _random);
        _current = _current - _current ~/ 1;
        _ctrl.reset();
        //_ctrl.stop();
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: But you placed `ctrl.addStatusListener()` at `initState()` method.
and I want to it at when animation is completed.

Comment: @Shruti Ramnandan Sharma why do you want it at when animation is completed？it just a callback.You can judge whether it is completed according to the `status` parameter.For example,`status == AnimationStatus.completed`

Comment: Becoz I want to call a dialogbox when animation is completed.

Comment: @Shruti Ramnandan Sharma so you can just judge whether it is completed according to the `AnimationStatus` status.